# Are business development and market research questions appropriate on programmers?

Tags: discussion

Here's a recent example: [Is developing for a niche tablet market worth it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78172/nook-color-development-market-stats-and-ease-of-promoting-an-equivalent-android)

is this kind of question appropriate for programmers? If not, is there a sister site where it should be migrated?

Answer (score 3):

The question needed a good clean up, but I think it's on-topic here.

Per [the FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), business concerns that affect developers on-topic here. In this case, the basic question was whether it's worth it to develop for a currently-niche tablet market if you want to get into mobile development, which is a question I think most mobile developers will have to grapple with.

Comment: Is that a question for developers or a question for people who manage developers, or a question for executives and strategic decision makers?

Comment: @jmort253 in this case, it was a developer who bought a tablet and wanted to know if it was worth getting into tablet development.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is [Answers.Onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com/), but I'm not familiar with it enough to say to be able to say with 100% certainty that the question should be migrated there. I'm pretty sure it'd be okay, though.